# bc: get the sum of a list of num

Tags: unix, bc

```
Jack   10
J      10 
A      20 
Lu cal 20
A bc U 20
```

I want to get the sum of these nums: 10+10+20+20+20 = 80

but I can't use `cat input|cut -d " " -f 3` to get the num, how can I do it?

Comment: The digits seem to start in column 8 if you're supposed to use `cut`; that should be a hint to get you going.  You don't need `cat` either.  You might need to use `awk` to do the summing, or `sed` to insert necessary extra characters.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use grep + paste + bc

```
$ grep -oE '[0-9]+' file
10
10
20
20
20

$ grep -oE '[0-9]+' file | paste -s -d + - 
10+10+20+20+20

$ grep -oE '[0-9]+' file | paste -s -d + - | bc
80
```

instead grep, you can use cut

```
$ cut -c 8- file
```

or just awk

```
$ awk '{print $NF}' file
```

BUT if you can use awk, you can sum using awk

```
$ awk '{total += $NF} END { print total }' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your file is called input.txt:

```
echo $(sed 's/[^0-9]*\([0-9]*\).*/\1+/' input.txt) '0' | bc
```

(I'm sure there is a more elegant way to do it with sed or perhaps awk, this is just a quick hack to add a terminating '0' to make bc happy.  Run different parts of the command separately to figure out what's going on)

Answer (score 0):

You could replace all whitespace with a + and pipe the result to bc

echo "5   6  2" | sed -E -e 's/\s+/+/g' | bc